# How can I screen capture a Windows 7 desktop and login screen? (i.e. remote monitoring)

Tags: windows, screenshot, headless, remote-management

My company has about 50 - 60 machines that we need to manage remotely.

They are set to automatically login but I'd like to perform the following activities:

- Capture screenshot (for diagnostic purposes, if something isn't working)
- Start/stop/kill processes
- Start/stop/kill services
- Reboot machine

This seems simple enough but I'd like to get information on the best approach for doing this.  My biggest problem is capturing a screenshot "no matter what is going on".  For example, if I write a Windows Service, it can't capture the desktop session screen or the login screen.

EDIT: I've prefer to make this a Windows Service so it can run even if the user isn't logged in (i.e. if a problem occurs with the auto-login) but that doesn't seem possible.  Furthermore, I'd also like to capture a screen if somebody RDPs in the machine.  Basically, I want to know exactly what is going on with each machine and monitor it remotely.

Comment: The primary job of the Secure Desktop is to make this impossible.  This is heavily buy, not build.

Comment: you may be able to send wmi commands to a remote box (which wouldn't help with screen capture, but might for reboot)

Answer (score 1):

**Remote Capture Screen Shots**

[Boxcutter](http://keepnote.org/boxcutter/) will do this (I dont know about the login screen though,  however in theory if you run it with PSExec below it should)

**Start/stop/kill processes & Start/stop/kill services**

PSExec, PSList, PSKill, PSService  all part of [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) will work here

**Reboot machine**

run shutdown command via PSExec  or run shutdown command with -m flag and the PC name you want to shutdown.

PSTools and remote shutdown do require / prefer the machines be on the same Domain as your PC and you must have admin rights to the PC's in question